# Templates in Magento-2?

Tags: magento2.2, php-7

I want to remove html tags from frontend. How to remove this?

```
 <?php
    $collectionTitle = $this->getCollectionTitle();
    ?>
    <div id="element" data-mage-init='{"accordion":{"openedState": "active", "collapsible": true, "active": false, "multipleCollapsible": true}}'> 
        <?php foreach ($collectionTitle as $item): ?>  
            <div data-role="collapsible">
                <div data-role="trigger"> 
                    <span>
                        <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($item->getCategoryName()); ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>    

            <?php $collection = $this->getCollection($item->getId()); ?> 
            <div data-role="content">
                <?php foreach ($collection as $items): ?>             
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($items->getQuestion()); ?> 
                    <?php echo $block->escapeHtml($items->getAnswer()); ?>            
                <?php endforeach; ?> 
            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
</div>
```

**Faq.php**

```
<?php

namespace Xxx\ManageFaqs\Block\Faq;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;
use Xxx\ManageFaqs\Model\Faqcat;
use Xxx\ManageFaqs\Model\Faq;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class Collection extends Template
{

    protected $_resource;
    public function __construct(Context $context, Faqcat $connection, Faq $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
        $this->modelConnection = $connection;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function getCollectionTitle()
    {
        $collection = $this->modelConnection->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
        return $collection;
    }

    public function getCollection($categoryname)
    {
        $connection = $this->model->getCollection();
        $connection->addFieldToFilter('category_name', $categoryname)->addFieldToFilter('status', 1);
        return $connection;
    }

}
```

Comment: could you try with strip_tags($item->getCategoryName())

Comment: but the content alignment was missing

Comment: if any aother way is possible.........

Comment: using escapeHtml is not working?

Comment: Yes,its not working

Comment: could you show your block file code?

Comment: updated my post

Comment: how to use escapehtml?

Comment: Its default working for template file.

Comment: working............

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: how to use escapeHtml in my template?

Comment: Have you made any change?

Comment: I have mention in file .but it throw html tags.while using strip_tags,it remove alignment in my faqs

Comment: no.............

Comment: Any idea.......